# Связанные между собой поля формы на js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите хороший скрипт для выбора например страны и города как показано на фото ниже но чтобы скрипт был только на js , баз данных и php ненужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: без баз данных вы будете сразу подгружать ВСЕ города в мире, например?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл примерно такое: [тут](https://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/adding-dropdown-country-state-list-dynamically-into-your-html-form-by-javascript/). Но! Приходилось как-то работать с таким, вообщем скажу одно, такой объём данных хранить у клиента, очень плохо и без БД будет трудно.. Со странами все хорошо, но вот с городами все намного хуже, т.к. их очень и очень много! БД город импортировалась у меня, примерно 3 часа...

Comment: Спасибо скрипт не плохой, я его немножко усовершенствовал и зжал через онлайн компрессор js

Answer (score 1):

Подобное всегда можно написать, используя API, как свое так и стороннего сервера (возможно будут сложности с CORS), как пример, простенький модуль взаимодействия с [GEO API VK](https://vk.com/dev/database.getCities)

```js
var GeoAPI = GeoAPI || {};
GeoAPI = (function() {
  var settings,
    options = [],
    newOption;

  var _render = function(data, $parent, cb) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
      newOption = '<option value="' + item.id + '" id="' + i + '">' + item.title + '</option>';
      options.push(newOption);
    });
    $parent.html(options);
    options = [];
    cb($parent);
  }

  var _getCountry = function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries",
      data: {
        'v': settings.version,
        'need_all': settings.country.need_all,
        'count': settings.country.count
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data, status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
          return false;
        }
        console.log(data.response, status);

        _render(data.response, settings.selectCountry, function($el) {
          $el.prop('disabled', false);
        });
      },
      error: function() {

      }
    });
  }

  var _getCity = function(country_id) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCities",
      data: {
        'v': settings.version,
        'need_all': 0,
        'country_id': country_id
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data, status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
          return false;
        }
        console.log(data.response, status);

        _render(data.response, settings.selectCity, function($el) {
          $el.prop('disabled', false);
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        //response([]);
      }
    });
  }
  return {
    init: function(options) {
      settings = $.extend({}, options || {})
      if (!settings.selectCountry && !settings.selectCity) {
        return false;
      } else {
        settings.selectCity.prop('disabled', true);
        settings.selectCountry.prop('disabled', true);
      }

      console.log(settings);
      _getCountry();

      settings.selectCountry.on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        settings.selectCity.prop('disabled', true);
        if ((parseInt(this.value, 10)) > 0) {
          _getCity(this.value);
        }

      });
    }
  }

})();

GeoAPI.init({
  selectCountry: $('#country'),
  selectCity: $('#city'),
  version: '5.5',
  country: {
    need_all: 1,
    count: 234
  }
});
```

```html
<select name="variant_id" id="country" class="variant_select">
  <option class="">Выберите страну</option>
</select>

<select name="variant_id" id="city" class="variant_select">
  <option class="">Выберите Город</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```